# debian dead when copy over 1GB

Tags: debian, cp, shutdown

I have a Debian Squeeze system with an AMD64 processor.
When I try copy over 1 GB, the computer dies (no reboot, completely down), and the logs don't contain anything useful.

The temperature of the processor is ~42º.

Comment: could you please give details of your copying command/operation.

Comment: Do you have swap disabled?

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM do you have?

You might be doing something that is causing the machine to either hit some bad RAM or hit a out-of-memory error.

Comment: Booting to memtest is the first thing I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

I change the power supply of 450 to 600